# Convert string to json valid value

Tags: json, ajax

I need to send a string to an end point that accepts data as JSON

```
    data = '{"data":"'+some_data+'"}';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "example.com/endpoint",
        data: data, 
        success: function(data) { console.log('data: ' + data); },
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json'
        });
```

now when providing `this is a text with " random text " , to test` as the value of `some_data` the ajax request throws an error in the console
but when providing `this is a text with \" random text \" , to test`  it works fine

Is there a built-in way to convert `"` to `\"` with out writing my own function

Comment: Tip: When asking for built-in ways it is usually helpful to specify the language you are working with (and also tag your question with it).

Comment: You have to show your end point header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do it that way when you can do

```
let data = {data: ' this is a text with " "  ' };
data = JSON.stringify(data);        
console.log(data);
```

Just use `JSON.stringify`